# AWS S3 Logs: AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-s3

I created an empty bucket and enabled logging via the web GUI with my aws root user. I created a second bucket to store these logs. The logfiles are generated but all of them look like the following:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>FCD6DC91A5BB8503</RequestId>
<HostId>
ROH2ON84Ef4x3DjcQJnJsE6Jz5h/Ke25sJoHy9hUmrMGo9Qi0eybWcS1ypTvt7r8Xny+mEwDlFw=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Do I need to configure something else to receive logs?

Answer (score 3):

Try clicking the "Download" or "Open" buttons rather than clicking the hyperlink under "Link"

Answer (score 1):

This to me looks like an error with the request you are sending, and not the logging feature. Are you sure that the requester has the correct permissions for the bucket? Check to make sure that the the requester has either the correct IAM privileges and/or the bucket allows access.

Comment: How do I know who the requester is? Right now Im the only one accessing my Bucket via the AWS Management Console.

Comment: I had the same error, and fixed the issue by selecting all the files in the S3 bucket and then going to "Actions" -> "Make Public".

Comment: Can you verify that you have the correct permissions to the bucket?